# How can I calculate the sum in a temporary column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have this code:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    name,
    result,
    CASE
        WHEN result = 1 THEN 100
        WHEN result = 2 THEN 80
        ELSE NULL
    END AS TemporaryColumn
FROM MyTable
```

And this is the table:

```
| ID | Name | result | TemporaryColumn |
----------------------------------------
|  1 |  A   |   1    |      100        |
----------------------------------------
|  2 |  B   |   1    |      100        |
----------------------------------------
|  3 |  C   |   2    |      80         |
----------------------------------------
|  1 |  A   |   2    |      80         |
----------------------------------------
|  2 |  B   |   1    |      100        |
----------------------------------------
|  3 |  C   |   2    |      80         |
----------------------------------------
```

I want to find the sum() of every ID, and the table should look like this:

```
| ID | Name | result | TemporaryColumn |
----------------------------------------
|  1 |  A   |   1    |      180        |
----------------------------------------
|  2 |  B   |   1    |      200        |
----------------------------------------
|  3 |  C   |   2    |      160        |
----------------------------------------
```

How can I query this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT
    ID,
    name,
    result,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN result = 1 THEN 100
            WHEN result = 2 THEN 80
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS TemporaryColumn
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID,
    name
```

Do not ethough that the `result` column cannot be ensured as from what I can tell, it is not unique, and should probably be excluded from the select list.

if that was the case, you would have to use

```
SELECT
    ID,
    name,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN result = 1 THEN 100
            WHEN result = 2 THEN 80
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS TemporaryColumn
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID,
    name
```

Comment: can you use temporary column then in the with clause if you wanted to filter on it